# Formatting output with 'printf' in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to format my output to look like it's in columns. I'm trying to use the [printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) function.

Here's what I have:

```
printf("%s %10s %12s %10s\n", "Qty", "Desc.", "Unit \$", "Total");

for ($he = 0; $he <= 6; $he++) {
    if (@quantity[$he] != 0) {
        printf("%d %10s %12.2f %10.2f\n", @quantity[$he], @selections[$he], @prices[$he], @prices[$he] * @quantity[$he])
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make it so that the second printf inside of the `if` statement of the `for` loop lines up with the "Qty", "Desc.", "Unit \$" and "Total."

Comment: The outputs just don't line up.

Comment: 4 errors are found using `use warnings;`!

Comment: How about something like  http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Text-Table-1.126/lib/Text/Table.pm ?

Comment: More info about printf can be found in the documentation for [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the same numbers in the two formats:

```
printf("%3s %10s %15s %13s\n", "Qty", "Desc.", "Unit \$", "Total");
```

and

```
printf("%3d %10s %12.2f %10.2f\n", @quantity[$he], @selections[$he], @prices[$he], @prices[$he]*@quantity[$he])
```

Note that 12.2 means (12 digits + 1 point + 2 digits), which is why I wrote 15 in the first format.  The same goes for the 13.

---

Also note that you're accessing array elements incorrectly.

Instead of `@quantity[$he]` use `$quantity[$he]`.  That is, replace the `@` with a `$`.

Comment: `@quantity[$he]` should be written `$quantity[$he]`.

Comment: This isn't working either.  When I implement this, there is only one space between $quantity[$he] and $selections[$he], but I want the two columns to match up :(

Comment: I think it may have to do with the strings in @selections being different lengths, any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Long time ago, Perl was mainly used for formatting files. It still has these capabilities although I haven't seen it used in a program since Perl 4.x came out.

Check out the [perlform](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html) documentation, the [format](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/format.html) function, and the [write](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/write.html) function.

I'd give you an example on what the code would look like except I haven't done it in years. Otherwise, use the `printf` statement. You can limit the size of a text field with a `%-10.10s` type of format. This says to left justify the string, and pad it out to 10 characters, but not more than 10 characters.

I also suggest you get a book on ***modern*** Perl. One that will teach you about [references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

I've rewritten your program to use references. Notice that all of the data is now in a single array instead of spread over four separate arrays that you hope you keep the index together.

I can talk about the *ENTREE* of `$item[1]` by saying `$item[1]->{ENTREE}`. It's easier to read and easier to maintain.

Also note that I've changed your `for` loop. In yours, you had to know that you had seven items. If you added a new item, you'd have to change your loop. In mine, I use `$#menu` to get the last index of my menu. I then use `(0..$#menu)` to automatically loop from 0 to the last item in the `@menu` array.

And, while you're at it:

- Notice the `printf` statement formats.
- Notice the use of `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. That will catch a lot of errors.
- Notice the preferred way I use parentheses and curly braces to mark off blocks of code. This is the preferred method.

And, now the program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @menu = (
    { ENTREE => "Hamburger",    PRICE => 3.49, QUANTITY => 3 },
    { ENTREE => "Frankfurter",  PRICE => 2.19, QUANTITY => 0 },
    { ENTREE => "French Fries", PRICE => 1.69, QUANTITY => 0 },
    { ENTREE => "Large Coke",   PRICE => 1.79, QUANTITY => 4 },
    { ENTREE => "Medium Coke",  PRICE => 1.59, QUANTITY => 0 },
    { ENTREE => "Small Coke",   PRICE => 1.39, QUANTITY => 0 },
    { ENTREE => "Onion Rings",  PRICE => 1.19, QUANTITY => 8 },
);

printf "%-3.3s %-10.10s %-6.6s %s\n\n", 'Qty', 'Desc.', 'Unit $', 'Total';

# Use $#menu to get the number of items in the array instead of knowing it's 6

foreach my $item (0..$#menu) {

    # Dereference $menu[$item] to make $menu_item a hash
    # This makes the syntax easier to read.
    my %menu_item = %{ $menu[$item] };

    if ( $menu_item{QUANTITY} ) {
        printf "%3d %-10.10s %9.2f %7.2f\n",
        $menu_item{QUANTITY}, $menu_item{ENTREE}, $menu_item{PRICE},
        $menu_item{QUANTITY} * $menu_item{PRICE};
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Qty Desc.      Unit $ Total

  3 Hamburger  3.49   10.47
  4 Large Coke 1.79    7.16
  8 Onion Ring 1.19    9.52
```

Comment: Why don't you just do a `foreach my $item (@menu)`?

Comment: I thought of the same thing a few hours after I posted my answer. I got thrown off from the original `for` loop where the OP was using an index. That's work better. Each `$item` is a reference to a hash.