# Getting fixed width columnar output using 'printf' in Perl

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting output with 'printf' in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038611/formatting-output-with-printf-in-perl)

```
my @selections = ("Hamburger","Frankfurter","French Fries","Large Coke","Medium Coke","Small Coke","Onion Rings");
my @prices = (3.49, 2.19, 1.69, 1.79, 1.59, 1.39, 1.19);
my @quantity = (3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 8);

printf("%s %10s %12s %10s\n", "Qty", "Desc.", "Unit \$", "Total");

for($meh = 0; $meh <= 6; $meh++)
{
    if($quantity[$meh] != 0)
    {
        printf("%d %10s %9.2f %7.2f\n", $quantity[$meh], $selections[$meh], $prices[$meh], $prices[$meh]*$quantity[$meh])
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to make the columns line up. I followed the suggestions of another post, but it still isn't working.

Comment: Repeating the same vague question is not going to help!

Comment: What is vague? There is something that is wrong with the printf but I can't figure out what it is!

Comment: At least you provided something runnable this time. You don't say what you got and what you expect. But really, that doesn't matter because you have already been given the solution.

Comment: You need to specify the column width on the first column; otherwise, the values printed there will use whatever's needed, and the rest will follow in fixed layouts to the right of the variable bit.  When formatting for columnar output, only the last column can be variable width.

Comment: If they all have a width of 12, how can I specify this in the program.  I thought %10s, for example, specified a width of 10?

Comment: The `%d` needs to be `%12d` or `%-12d`; the `%s` needs to be `%12s` or `%-12s`.  The difference is left justified vs right justified.  But all formats need to have a width specified, or you need to know that the input strings are all the same width.

Comment: it specifies a minimum width; if the data is bigger, that will break your formatting.  so specify the maximum width you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the columns to be exactly aligned based on dynamic input data, you need to make two passes over the rows. The first time through, record the maximum length of each column. Then construct a format string using those lengths. Finally, print each row using that format string.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @selections = ("Hamburger","Frankfurter","French Fries","Large Coke","Medium Coke","Small Coke","Onion Rings");
my @prices = (3.49, 2.19, 1.69, 1.79, 1.59, 1.39, 1.19);
my @quantity = (3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 8);

my @rows;
push @rows, ["Qty", "Desc.", "Unit \$", "Total"];

# construct table data as a two-dimensional array
for (my $meh = 0; $meh < @selections; $meh++) {
    next unless $quantity[$meh];
    push @rows, [$quantity[$meh], $selections[$meh], $prices[$meh], $prices[$meh]*$quantity[$meh]];
}

# first pass over rows: compute the maximum width for each column
my @widths;
for my $row (@rows) {
    for (my $col = 0; $col < @$row; $col++) {
        $widths[$col] = length $row->[$col] if length $row->[$col] > ($widths[$col] // 0);
    }
}

# compute the format. for this data, it works out to "%-3s %-11s %-6s %-5s\n"
my $format = join(' ', map { "%-${_}s" } @widths) . "\n";

# second pass: print each row using the format
for my $row (@rows) {
    printf $format, @$row;
}
```

That yields this output:

```
Qty Desc.       Unit $ Total
3   Hamburger   3.49   10.47
4   Large Coke  1.79   7.16 
8   Onion Rings 1.19   9.52
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your strings are more than 10 characters long, and Perl won't cut them unless you specify a maximum width, which is given after the dot for strings (`%10.10s`). Also, you may want to use a negative number so they become aligned to the left (`%-10.10s`).

Comment: THANK YOU. Most helpful response yet!

Comment: What if I want the full word to show, but the widths to be the same?  So if I have "French Fries" and "Small Coke", even though they're different sizes, the spaces will be the same?

Comment: Then use a width that's large enough (12 or more).

Comment: That doesn't work either.  "French Fries" will have 12 spaces after it and "Small Coke" will have 12 spaces after it; they're different lengths, so the "12 spaces" won't be the same.

Comment: What are you talking about?! It will add 0 spaces to French Fries and 2 spaces to Small Code. (You need to tag  me with @ikegami if you want me to see your comments)

Comment: @Bob John, when someone suggests something, don't just say "that doesn't work", show what you tried and what happened (by editing your question, for example).  Because if someone says something will work and it doesn't for you, the error is as likely to be in how you tried as it is to be in the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Long time ago, Perl was mainly used for formatting files. It still has this capabilities although I haven't seen it used in a program since Perl 4.x came out.

Check out the [perlform](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html) documentation, the [format](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/format.html) function, and the [write](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/write.html) function.

I'd give you an example on what the code would look like except I haven't done it in years. Otherwise, use the `printf` statement. You can limit the size of a text field with a `%-10.10s` type of format. This says to left justify the string, and pad it out to 10 characters, but not more than 10 characters.

I also suggest you get a book on ***modern*** Perl. One that will teach you about [references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

I've rewritten your program to use references. Notice that all of the data is now in a single array instead of spread over four separate arrays that you hope you keep the index together.

I can talk about the *ENTREE* of `$item[1]` by saying `$item[1]->{ENTREE}`. It's easier to read and easier to maintain.

Also note that I've changed your `for` loop. In yours, you had to know that you had seven items. If you added a new item, you'd have to change your loop. In mine, I use `$#menu` to get the last index of my menu. I then use `(0..$#menu)` to automatically loop from 0 to the last item in the `@menu` array.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @menu = (
    { ENTREE => "Hamburger",    PRICE => 3.49, QUANTITY => 3 },
    { ENTREE => "Frankfurter",  PRICE => 2.19, QUANTITY => 0 },
    { ENTREE => "French Fries", PRICE => 1.69, QUANTITY => 0 },
    { ENTREE => "Large Coke",   PRICE => 1.79, QUANTITY => 4 },
    { ENTREE => "Medium Coke",  PRICE => 1.59, QUANTITY => 0 },
    { ENTREE => "Small Coke",   PRICE => 1.39, QUANTITY => 0 },
    { ENTREE => "Onion Rings",  PRICE => 1.19, QUANTITY => 8 },
);

printf "%-3.3s %-10.10s %-6.6s %s\n\n", 'Qty', 'Desc.', 'Unit $', 'Total';

# Use $#menu to get the number of items in the array instead of knowing it's 6

foreach my $item (0..$#menu) {

    # Dereference $menu[$item] to make $menu_item a hash
    # This makes the syntax easier to read.
    my %menu_item = %{ $menu[$item] };

    if ( $menu_item{QUANTITY} ) {
        printf "%3d %-10.10s %9.2f %7.2f\n",
        $menu_item{QUANTITY}, $menu_item{ENTREE}, $menu_item{PRICE},
        $menu_item{QUANTITY} * $menu_item{PRICE};
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Qty Desc.      Unit $ Total

  3 Hamburger  3.49   10.47
  4 Large Coke 1.79    7.16
  8 Onion Ring 1.19    9.52
```